# Proof of inequality with the help of markov

Tags: probability, inequality

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be independently and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p \in(0,1)$. Consider also $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{p e^h}{p e^h+(1-p)}, h \geq 0.$
> Define
> $$
> S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k, \quad M_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k.
> $$

The first exercise was to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(M_n=k\right)=\frac{e^{h k}}{\left(p e^h+(1-p)\right)^n} \mathbb{P}\left(S_n=k\right), \quad k \geq 0 .
$$
The second one was to show
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(S_n \geq k\right) \leq\left(p e^h+(1-p)\right)^n e^{-h k}.
$$
I did both but I have trouble with the last one:

> Give an alternative proof of the inequality using an appropriate version of the Markov inequality.

Any hints on how to tackle this one?

Comment: Yes: $\mathbb E[S_n]=np$ and  $\mathbb E[M_n]=n\frac{p e^h}{p e^h+(1-p)}$.  Both are binomially distributed.

Comment: Hint: $\Pr(S_n \geq k) = \Pr(hS_n \geq hk) = \Pr(e^{hS_n} \geq e^{hk})$.  Apply Markov and complete the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $f(n)=e^{hn}.$ Using the Markov inequality, it follows.
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(S_n \geq k\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(f(S_n) \geq f(k)\right)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[f(S_n)\right]}{f(k)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[f(S_n)\right]}{e^{hk}}=e^{- hk}\sum_{j=0}^n f(j)\mathbb{P}(S_n=j).
$$
Since we have a Bernoulli distribution and therefore the sum is binomially distributed, it follows that
$$
e^{-hk}\sum_{j=0}^n e^{hj}\binom{n}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}=e^{-hk}\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}(e^hp)^j(1-p)^{n-j}
$$
and with the binomial theorem
$$
e^{-hk} (pe^h+(1-p))^n. \quad \square
$$